# Can This Expression Chain Be Rewritten Without Parentheses?

Tags: elixir

So I was playing with streams in Elixir and I was playing with the |> operator as well; I have a lot of experience playing with F# and so it feels pretty natural. So I tried this:

```
1..10 |> Stream.map &(&1 * &1) |> Enum.to_list
```

Just to spit out a list of the first ten squares.  But it didn't work. No problem; just seemed to be a problem of operator precedence because this works fine:

```
(1..10 |> Stream.map &(&1 * &1)) |> Enum.to_list
```

But I was wondering if this could be rewritten without having to parenthesize the first half of the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you're calling `Stream.map` without parentheses, and then try to pipe. I must admit, I'm not sure of the mechanics, but your original call seems to be interpreted as:

```
1..10 |> Stream.map(&(&1 * &1) |> Enum.to_list)
```

I would rewrite this to use parens in the function call:

```
1..10 |> Stream.map(&(&1 * &1)) |> Enum.to_list
```

Personally, I mostly use parens in function calls. The exceptions to this are zero arg function calls, macro calls, and occasional IO.puts/inspect calls (which I usually do just for debugging purposes).

I find this approach to be very helpful, in particular when piping, because it removes possible ambiguities.

Comment: I  see your point.  I  was looking for something analogous to F#'s pipe backwards operator <¦ but I  am sure you're right about how it's getting associated.

Comment: It's partially my own fault. I'm used to F# and in F# the argument to <Collection>.map would not be in parentheses.

Comment: It's not your fault. Elixir allows optional parens, so this can cause occasional ambiguities. It's a double-edged sword. Owing to optional parens, we can write `def my_fun do ... end` without parens, but can also end up in the situation you had.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too, so kindly point out if I am wrong, but you can do it like this too right ?

`iex(11)> 1..10 |> Enum.map(&(&1 * &1))

[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]`

Comment: Actually I can already see the difference here: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Stream.html where Enums are eager while Streams are lazy.